# chart.js data api options in html

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I've been trying to create a half doughnut using the chart js library starting from a template where the chart options are provided using html attributes:

```
 <canvas
        id="myChart"
        class="ex-graph"
        width="200" height="200"
        data-chart="doughnut"
        data-value="[{ value: 230, color: '#1ca8dd', label: 'Returning' }, { value: 130, color: '#1bc98e', label: 'New' }]"
        data-segment-stroke-color="#252830"></canvas>
```

The options that I want to provide are:

```
   options: {
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI
}
```

So I tried without success the following:

```
<canvas
    class="ex-graph"
    width="200" height="200"
    data-chart="doughnut"
    data-value="[{ value: 230, color: '#1ca8dd', label: 'Returning' }, { value: 130, color: '#1bc98e', label: 'New' }]"
    data-segment-stroke-color="#252830"

    data-options="[{
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI},
  {circumference: 1 * Math.PI
}]"
   >
  </canvas>
```

Is it possible to use the options attribute as a html attribute?

Comment: where in chartjs docs does it say you can use html attributes for any of that? The docs only seem to mention using javascript.

Comment: I might be mixing two things, 'The data API allows you to use Chart.js arguments and options by writing HTML. Take any option provided by Chart.js and simply hypenate it as an HTML attribute. For example, the doughnut's `segmentStrokeColor` option, becomes `data-segment-stroke-color`'.[link]( http://goryu.sakura.ne.jp/apollon/docs/components/plugin-chartjs.md)

Comment: k. not sure Data API is part of Chart.js. But "rotation" and "circumference" on the options. "options" is not an option.

Comment: Didn't work as given data-options but they are options for this type of chart. I should have included the documentation for the doughnut/pie initially  [link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)

Comment: I think the problem is "1 * Math.PI" is not JSON.  You'd need a parseable value, like 3.141972

Comment: also try just data-rotation='3.141972', data-circumference='3.141972'

Comment: My apologies here, I was working with the older version of chart.js (v1) those options seem to be unavailable with this version.

Comment: toYoann_R, do you by any chance have a link to the ChartJS Data API? (not the ChartJS Api)

Comment: What I found later is that the data api is just javascript that takes the arguments given in the html to generate the graphs. I was using the templates from bootstrap that are a bit old and this part of javascript is contained in the toolkit.js and generates the graph with the processed argument: `new Chart(element.getContext('2d')).Doughnut(data, options)`